# Checking the conclusions made are right or wrong regarding interaction between a spherical conductor and a charge inside it

Tags: electrostatics

Consider a setup of a spherical shell conductor  with a charge kept  at a distance d from centre (d<R). Are these conclusions right ?

- If the earthing was done then the induce charge distribution on the inner surface of the shell is not dependent on the outer surface charge , and so earthing has no effect on inside charge distribution .
- The outer surface charge distribution will be uniform.  Infact total positive or negative charge outside is  zero .
- The reason inner surface charge distribution doesnt depend on earthing or anything happening outside the shell is because the conductor always shield it from outside field.
- The whole system is not in **electrostatics condition** when just the charge and conductor is present in a gravity free space . Since there is a attrative force causing them to move towards each other .

Answer (score 0):

- Yes this is correct. Viewed from outside, the induced interior surface charge perfectly cancels out the point charge. Any additional surface charge would result in an electric field in the conductor as it would not be able to cancel it using outer surface charge.
- Yes, in the earthed case. If not you'll have a uniform surface charge to adjust the desired voltage (with respect to $\infty$):
  $$
  \sigma = \frac{\epsilon_0 V}{r_o}
  $$
  with $r_o$ the outer radius.
- Yes, that's correct, no matter the outside influence.
- I see what you mean, but to rigorously apply electrostatics, your charges must not move. Equilibrium will be obtained by applying an external force maintaining the conductor and the charge in place.

Hope this helps and tell me if you need more details.